# ngAnimate affects highcharts layout

Tags: css, angularjs, highcharts, ng-animate

I'm using highcharts-ng to display some chart. I now decided to add some animations to the application, but as I include ngAnimate as a module's dependency, I get some charts' layout messed up (they don't fit their container anymore). Is this a known issue? May this be related to my css of that particular part of the page? In such a case, would this mean there's some css class which is reserved for ngAnimate to work that I could have modified?

Is there a way I can verify this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to see it in chrome inspector/other developer tool, you can figure out which css are conflicting

Comment: Are you able to recreate your example as live demo ?

Comment: I did a codepen to reproduce the problem, and the two libraries didn't collide. It may be something else, but I don't know how to inspect the problem, on dev tools nothing changes after including ngAnimate